How to fetch CompactLayouts that are assigned to certain user profiles + record type ids
/services/data/v62.0/tooling/query?q=select+LayoutId,+RecordTypeId,+TableEnumOrId+from+ProfileLayout

I think the query above is only good for fetching page layouts? Even though I am not 100% sure. When I also include in it Layout.LayoutType the value that comes back is always Standard.
Even though I would expect it to be Page/Search/Compact.
So, how do I do the same for CompactLayouts? Thanks in advance!

Does this answer your question? Querying fields of a particular pagelayout w.r.t Profile and Object

No, it is not what I want, the API that you have linked is fetching metadata for recordIds, I need for recordTypeIds. I do not have recordIds.

The UI API is intended for your use case: Get Record Layout. Without providing a record ID to a UI API endpoint, you won't get profile-specific info.
